# How to reset coordinate if crosses float limits in an infinite running game in libgdx

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, libgdx, game-engine

I am new to the world of libgdx, I am developing an infinite running game. I am curious to know if a player is running for several hours and its position keeps on changing lets says its x value is increasing countinously, then what happens if position crosses float max limits. Some of the discussion suggests that we need to reset the coordinates after certain moments of time http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/491411/best-practices-for-endless-runner-type-games.html. But I am not sure how to achieve this in libgdx.

Comment: if you will simply increment it by one and then if u have a FPS of 60 then i will say probably lot of time before it will happen, just do the maths, the result will make u feel good beleive me, even i am surprised

Comment: Do you generate the level just off the edge of the screen? How do you currently make it "endless"? Looping certain tiles?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever method you have of keeping the level "infinite" (*without actually using up "infinite" memory*), is where you can tie in "resetting" your character and level's position most conveniently.

---

In many cases, your character doesn't even need to "actually" be moving - the level can just be moving past him to the left.. similar to how people use a treadmill to run, but actually they stay in place. Destroy the pieces that move off-screen to the left and keep them coming on the right.

Alternatively, the character might be running along and at some convenient point you can move the entire level and the character back to the origin with nobody the wiser. It just has to happen "all at once", *without physics methods of movements*, and for *every* position you store. On slower devices, depending on the number of objects you have to move, this could result in a long single frame of lag... so use with caution.